# Study the convergence of this series of functions: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^x\left ( \tan\frac{x^n}{n}-\sin\frac{x^n}{n} \right )$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

I tried to study the convergence of this series: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }n^x\left ( \tan\frac{x^n}{n}-\sin\frac{x^n}{n} \right )$$ 
I started to study the pointwise convergence with the limit for $n \to \infty$ of the argument, but without success. 
Can you help me to solve this excercise?

Comment: What is sen? $\sin$ or $\sec$ or maybe something else?

Comment: @wythagoras it looks to be the spanish version of $sin$, since "sinus" in spanish is "seno".

Comment: @SergeyRusakov More likely Italian, since the OP is form Italia.

Comment: @wythagoras agree.

Comment: It's $sin$ sorry.

Comment: @Aoeilda what's the area you are interested in? I think, I have a proof of pointwise convergence in $[-1, 1]$ but leaving this interval leads to at the very least the possibility of $tan\frac{x^n}{n}$ being undefined.

Comment: The excercise don't talk about a particular area, but only to study the pointwise and uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin x = x+O(x^3)$ and $\tan x = x+O(x^3)$ you get $\tan x - \sin x\sim x^3$ and thus the terms asymptotically equivalent to
$$
n^{x-3}·x^{3n}.
$$